# Regular Expression - Extract Tracking ID from Google Analytic script

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract UA-123456-7 from the following Google Analytic using regular expression. I think I'm too close, but I'm not sure it is even possible.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-123456-7");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
</script>
```

Here is what I get when I run at [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html)

Regex: `^[<>%\w_\/.:;()\+-=?"]*(.*?)[<>\w_.;()]*$`

Replacement text: `$1`

Result:  `gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-140422-1"`

Could someone please shed the light? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a substring ?

Find the position of the string "_getTracker(" -> Pos A

same for string ")" -> Pos B

And substring between Pos A and Pos B.

Is that helpfull ?

Comment: Here is what I end up with. Thank you for your tip. text = text.replace(/[\r\n\s]+/g, ''); // Remove new line characters
text = text.replace(/^(.*?)UA/g, ''); // Remove up to UA
text = text.replace(/['"](.*?)$/g, ''); // Remove the rest